# Move specific files to new directory while maintaining original directory structure

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

I want to move directories (and their sub-directories and files) that are named starting with "cd_" from a large number of "ab-" directories found within a pre-defined source directory:

SRC = '/home/user/source'

to a new (destination) directory:

DST = '/home/user/destination'

The (**partial**) directory structure of SRC is as follows:

```
home/user/source
    ab-0001
        cd_data_1
        cd_data_2
        ef_data_1
        gh_data_1
    ab-0002
        sub_folder
            cd_data_1
            ef_data_1
    ab-0003
        sub_folder
            cd_data_1
        sub_folder_2
            cd_data_1
            ef_data_1
```

DST folder is initially empty but after moving the files, I want DST and SRC to appear as follows:

SRC:

```
home/user/source
    ab-0001
        ef_data_1
        gh_data_1
    ab-0002
        sub_folder
            ef_data_1
    ab-0003
        sub_folder
        sub_folder_2
            ef_data_1
```

DST:

```
/home/user/destination
    ab-0001
        cd_data_1
        cd_data_2
    ab-0002
        sub_folder
            cd_data_1             
    ab-0003
        sub_folder
            cd_data_1
        sub_folder_2
            cd_data_1
```

Note that there are a large number of "ab-" directories (with variable structures) in SRC, so we cannot hard code each one.

So far, I have only been able to identify the directories that need to be moved with:

```
 for root_dir_path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(SRC):
      for dir in sub_dirs:
          if dir.startswith("cd_"):
              print("Root Directory Path:", root_dir_path)
              print("Sub Directories named 'cd_*':", dir)
```

I am stuck on how to address the variability in the structure of the "ab-" directories to move the files to DST as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there. You are searching for 'cd_' in the list of sub directories, but you have to look into the list of files. Assuming your source folder only has all directory    -name starting with "ab-", you can try below method.

```
SRC = 'home/user/source'
DEST = 'home/user/target'
for root_dir_path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(SRC):
      for file_name in files:
          if file_name[:3]=='cd_': # 3 because len('cd_')=3 # string slicing
            # Your required file with cd_ prefix
            src_path = 'home/user'+root_dir_path+file_name
            dest_path = src_path.replace(SRC, DEST, 1)
            # move file
            shutil.move(src_path, dest_path)
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Looking for files instead of directories didn't give me the results I was looking for. I'm running the script from SRC so 'home/user' in src_path wasn't needed, which is good because I want to avoid hard coding if possible. A "/" was needed between root_dir_path and file_name (which becomes "dir" in my answer. My mistake for not specifying that the script should only act on "cd_" subdirectories since non-"cd_" directories are sometimes present. Ultimately, the src_path and dest_path lines helped me find the solution I was looking for. With your contribution, I am posting the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil

SRC = 'home/user/source'
DST = 'home/user/target'

for root_dir_path, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(SRC):
    for dir in sub_dirs:
        if dir.startswith("cd_"):
            src_path = root_dir_path+"/"+dir
            dest_path = src_path.replace(SRC, DST, 1)
            shutil.move(src_path, dest_path)
```